# What does the y parameter do in sklearn.decomposition.DicitonaryLearning.fit?

Tags: scikit-learn

`sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.fit` has parameters `X` which is the training vector shape (n_samples, n_features) and a parameter `y` which is unexplained.

Other functions of the same class also have paramter `y` which are "target values" is an array of shape [n_samples].

I don't know where the concept of "target value" comes in when creating a dictionary.

Here is a link to the docs: http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.html#sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ignored and just there for technical reasons.

Comment: any explanation on what these technical reasons are ?